# Symfony 6 сделать уникальной комбинацию полей в энтити

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Пытаюсь сделать уникальные записи в БД с определенной комбинацией полей, но почему-то это не работает...

```
#[Table(name: '`user_group`',
    uniqueConstraints: [new ORM\UniqueConstraint(name: "map_unique", columns: ["user_id", "group_id"], 
    options: ["message" => "This user already exists in the given group"])])]
```

Comment: Почитайте тут 
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/9540
и тут 
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/attributes-reference.html#attrref_table